# htaccess redirection of multiple URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I usually use this site to solve my problems, but for the first time I couldn't find a proper question, so forgive me if it actually exists!

Currently, I have valid URLs in such format:

```
http://www.example.com/index/modules/news/article.php?storyid=15807
```

That the number at the end is generated dynamically by CMS and therefore changes for any new content published.

In order to use shorter URLs, I want these pages to be accessible by subdomain in such format:

```
http://news.example.com/n15807
```

Please help me and let me know if there is a better option rather than using htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Sure!  You can use mod_rewrite in apache's virtual host config file.

Sarcasm aside, the way to reroute a url is to *use the tool that accepts the url* and does something with it, which in the case of the typical php installation is apache. If PHP were able to accept connections without the use of an http server, then PHP could do it.  I suppose one could build a server out of php and run it as a singleton, but I've never heard of such a thing.

So here's the thing, using .htaccess and mod_rewrite isn't so hard, if you understand what you're trying to do.  In your case, you want to be able to translate news.example.com/n15807 into that really long uri.  That really long uri is what the server will actually load.

mod_rewrite in effect matches against a regular expression and replaces it with another uri.  So you would attempt to match something like `^([^w]{3}).example.com/([a-z])([0-9]+)$` and use it to replace values in `/index/modules/$1/article.php?storyid=$3`  (I have no idea what the n in front of the number is supposed to mean.)

The regex I gave is intended only to point you in the right direction; I haven't tested it. [EDIT - It definitely won't work as written; it's been a while since I worked on mod_rewrite.  But the idea is still valid.  FWIW, I wouldn't try to use subdomains, though]

Summary:  Use the tool that works with the urls.  The most accessible way is with .htaccess.  Once you figure it out, you're done.  You can reuse it over and over in future websites.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm not a .htaccess expert. Can you say it in its exact terms?

Comment: I'm not either... but you took the idea and ran with it.  Way to go!

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searches I finally got it!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^news.example.com$
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/index/modules/news/article.php?storyid=$1\#siteBody [R=301,L,NE]
```

Thought it might help someone someday not to spend as much time as I did!